# Highlight most recently inserted row GridView asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row

I have a paging GridView in my ASP.NET project in which I do insertions of human resources into a database. My GridView loads everytime all the human resources inserted into the data base. 
Now  everytime I add  a new row (human resource) or modify an existing one, I want it to be highlighted in the grid to make clear to the user that the operation was executed. I haven´t found a good way yet and the fact that the gridview is paged makes it more complex. I would appreciate some help :)

I'm adding the rows by binding de grid with a dataTable:

```
protected void llenarGrid()        //se encarga de llenar el grid cada carga de pantalla
    {
        DataTable recursosHumanos = crearTablaRH();
        DataTable dt = controladoraRecursosHumanos.consultarRecursoHumano(1, 0); // en consultas tipo 1, no se necesita la cédula

        Object[] datos = new Object[4];


        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                datos[0] = dr[0];
                datos[1] = dr[1];
                datos[2] = dr[2];
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]);
                String nomp = controladoraRecursosHumanos.solicitarNombreProyecto(id);
                datos[3] = nomp;
                recursosHumanos.Rows.Add(datos);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            datos[0] = "-";
            datos[1] = "-";
            datos[2] = "-";
            datos[3] = "-";
            recursosHumanos.Rows.Add(datos);
        }
        RH.DataSource = recursosHumanos;
        RH.DataBind();

    }



   protected DataTable crearTablaRH()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Cedula", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre Completo", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Rol", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre Proyecto");
        //dt.
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code and markup. It's hard to tell how you're inserting your rows if you don't do that, and it means that whoever is answering will have to spend less time working on it (so you're more likely to get an answer) and the answer will be more customized to your situation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I will edit the questiion soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the Primary Key / A unique value which uniquely identifies the row in View State when you are inserting the row :

Let's assume the first Column has unique value. Add below line at the end of your `llenarGrid()` method.

```
 ViewState["LastRowUniqueValue"] = datos[0];
```

Handle the `Page_PreRender` event, highlight the inserted row:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lastInsertedRowValue = string.Empty;

        // only highlight the row if last inserted values are NOT a Hyphen -

        if (ViewState["LastRowUniqueValue"] != "-")
        {
            // Assuming the Unique value is String, else cast accordingly
            string lastInsertedRowValue = (string)ViewState["LastRowUniqueValue"];

            int rowCnt = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
               string CellText = row.Cells[0].Text;
                if (CellText.Equals(lastInsertedRowValue))
                {
                    row.Attributes.Add(“bgcolor”, “Yellow”);
                    break;
                }
                rowCnt++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the `rowdatabound` event to find the row that has been edited and then assign a bootstrap css class to that row like this:

```
e.Row.CssClass = "danger";
```